# TextView not setText on onActivityResult Fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment

This is my code to scan **barcode** and set content to **TextView**:

```
public class scanCodeFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

  Button btnScan;
  TextView contentTxt;
  String substrCode, scanContent;
  View v;

  public scanCodeFragment(){
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scan_code, container, false);
    btnScan = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnScan);
    contentTxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.scan_content);

    btnScan.setOnClickListener(this);

    return v;
  }

  public void onClick(View v){
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnScan){
        IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
        scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (scanningResult != null) {
        scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        substrCode = scanContent.substring(2, 10);
        contentTxt.setText("NIS: " + substrCode);
    }
    else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Kode barcode salah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
  }
}
```

In `onActivityResult` method , I can't get the result after scan the barcode code. Before this code fragment, I can get the result from onActivityResult.

Comment: Where did you call `startActivityForResult()` ?

Comment: I not call startActivityForResult(). Where i must call startActivityForResult()?

Comment: read more https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: Maybe, `onActivityResult` on your fragment not call and call in its parent activity `onActivityResult`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this line `IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());` to this `IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);`.

The reason is that if you pass an Activity as parameter inside IntentIntegrator then on `initiateScan` will be called `activity.startActivityForResult(intent, code)` - so result won't be passed to fragment (try to check onActivityResult for parent Activity, it will be called). But if you pass Fragment as parameter inside IntentIntegrator - will be called `fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, code)`, so Android framework will be able to call onActivityResult inside your fragment for result.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what your initiateScan() so keep it if you need it

```
final int requestCode = 100;

public void onClick(View v){
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnScan){
      IntentIntegrator intent = new IntentIntegrator(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(RECIPE_EXTRA, extraObject);
            startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code snippet you have provided, I suggest you to create a separate `Activity` for scanning, instead of a `Class` file, in your case which is `IntentIntegrator`, and start it when your Scan `Button` is clicked.

So, create `IntentIntegratorActivity` and start it like this.

```
public void onClick(View v){
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnScan){
        IntentIntegratorActivity intent = new Intent(getActivity(), IntentIntegratorActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SCAN_INTENT_CODE);//Remember this code, which is an Integer value
    }
}
```

Then, in `OnCreate` method of `IntentIntegratorActivity`, do the scanning and return the scan data via an `Intent`.

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("SCAN_DATA_KEY", scanData);//Send scan data from here and remember the key SCAN_DATA_KEY
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

Then this data should be caught inside `onActivityResult` method in the `Fragment` `Class`.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case ConstList.SCAN_INTENT_CODE:
        String scanData = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_DATA_KEY");//Use this key to get the data. 
        //I have assumed that the data is String
        contentTxt.setText("NIS: " + scanData);//Set data to the Text field
        break;     
    }
}
```

Comment: What the meaning of SCAN_INTENT_CODE?

Comment: @NaufalPrakoso SCAN_INTENT_CODE is an Integer variable between 0-255, you have to define and make sure it does not exceed 256.

Answer (score 0):

**OnActivityResult() called only if you call 
startActivityForResult()**

I call the startActivityForResult() in Fragment and implement the onActivityResult in Fragment, the onActivityResult() will be called correctly.

you can not call startActivityForResult() in activity, otherwise the onActivityResult() in Fragment will not be called